# Integrate FileMerge.app into Finder using the Automator application to create a service

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, xcode

I was trying to adapt the accepted answer to this question. [How to integrate FileMerge.app into Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432509/how-to-integrate-filemerge-app-into-finder)

I'm on a mac with macOS Sonoma version 14.1.1. Unfortunately I get the following error message.

[image]

Doesn't it work as described in the linked answer? May be because it is 2 years old and things have changed? How can I make it work? The Idea remains the same, i.e my goal is to select two text files in finder and compare them.

Comment: The error message is saying `opendiff` is in Xcode, so If you don't have that installed something else will need to be used.

Comment: I have xcode installed. May be it has some issues. I'll try to uninstall it and reinstall

Comment: @red_menace I have re-installed xcode. Every thing looks fine from that perspective. But the same error remains. Any Ideas?

Comment: You can try running Xcode or use the command line tool `xcode-select` to switch the developer directory that is being used.

Comment: Can you try to use `$(xcode-select -p)/usr/bin/opendiff` instead of just `opendiff` in Automator?